# Full Calendar Custom view customize

Tags: fullcalendar

How to customise full calendar view as they mention the following url http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/ i am unable to get any of example as how to customize from scratch, any example would be appriciate

Answer (score 1):

```
 fcViews.weekList = WeekListView;

    // Store defaults here so we don't have to modify defaults.js
    defaults.titleFormat.weekList = "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}";
    defaults.columnFormat.weekList = 'MMM d, yyyy';
    defaults.buttonText.weekList = 'week';

    function WeekListView(element, calendar) {
      var t = this;

      // exports
      t.render = render;

      // imports
      ListView.call(t, element, calendar, 'weekList');
      var opt = t.opt;
      var renderList = t.renderList;
      var skipHiddenDays = t.skipHiddenDays;
      var getCellsPerWeek = t.getCellsPerWeek;
      var formatDates = calendar.formatDates;



  function render(date, delta) {

    if (delta) {
        addDays(date, delta * 7);
    }

    var start = addDays(cloneDate(date), -((date.getDay() - opt('firstDay') + 7) % 7));
    var end = addDays(cloneDate(start), 7);

    var visStart = cloneDate(start);
    skipHiddenDays(visStart);

    var visEnd = cloneDate(end);
    skipHiddenDays(visEnd, -1, true);

    var rowCnt = getCellsPerWeek();

    t.start = start;
    t.end = end;
    t.visStart = visStart;
    t.visEnd = visEnd;

    t.title = formatDates(
      visStart,
      addDays(cloneDate(visEnd), -1),
      opt('titleFormat')
    );

    renderList(rowCnt);
  }

}
```

and initialise it

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'weekList',
    events: testEvents
});
```

Refer this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nomatteus/dVGN2/3/